# Why is the degree 2 extension of R algebraically complete?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

Is it surprising to everyone that the degree 2 extension of R is algebraically complete, or is there an intuitive way to look at it to suggest that the algebraic completion of the complete ordered field is a plane?

Comment: You meant why $\Bbb{C}$ is algebraically closed. Any proof you like [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)?

Comment: Well once you realize that every polynomial of *odd* degree has at least one root in $\mathbb R$ (which has a lot to do with completeness and order structure of $\mathbb R$), this becomes quite a bit less surprising, although still not totally trivial. After all, they call it the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Why is it less surprising knowing that every polynomial of odd degree has a root in R?